# Flattening out an email chain data with specific users and minimum sent date Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you write a query to return the earliest record of an email sent to a specific person and have the result flattened out.

For instance I have an email chain specific to an ID like this:

```
ID   SENTTO  Date
A1   23      1/1/2015
A1   23      1/3/2015
A1   24      1/5/2015
A2   23      1/3/2015
A2   24      1/4/2015
A2   23      1/5/2015
A3   24      1/1/2015
A3   24      1/3/2015
```

Result:

```
ID   SENTTO23 Min(Date) SENTTO24 MIN(DATE)
A1   23       1/1/2015  24       1/5/2015
A2   23       1/3/2015  24       1/4/2015
A3   NULL     NULL      24       1/1/2015
```

I write a code that looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DATE)
FROM TABLEA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS TB1 ON TABLEAID=TABLEBID
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS TB2 ON TABLEAID=TABLEB2ID
WHERE (TB1.SENTTO = 23 OR TB1.SENTTO IS NULL)
AND (TB2.SENTTO = 24 OR TB2.SENTTO IS NULL)
```

BUT i get something like this where it either grabs just any dates or only grabs records containing both dates:

```
ID   SENTTO23 Min(Date) SENTTO24 MIN(DATE)
A1   23       1/1/2015  24       1/5/2015
A2   23       1/3/2015  24       1/4/2015
A3   24       1/1/2015  24       1/1/2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to get each `MIN(DATE) GROUP BY ID, SENTTO`. You can use this query:

```
SELECT
    ID, SENTTO, MinDate = MIN(Date)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID, SENTTO
ORDER BY ID, SENTTO
```

This will give you:

```
ID   SENTTO      MinDate
---- ----------- ----------
A1   23          2015-01-01
A1   24          2015-01-05
A2   23          2015-01-03
A2   24          2015-01-04
A3   24          2015-01-01
```

Now that you have the `MIN(DATE)`, you can use the above result to `PIVOT` the data. Here is one way using dynamic crosstab:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    ID' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN SENTTO = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SENTTO) + ' THEN SENTTO END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('SENTTO'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SENTTO)) + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN SENTTO = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SENTTO) + ' THEN MinDate END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('MIN(DATE)') + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT SENTTO FROM Tbl
) t

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM(
    SELECT
        ID, SENTTO, MinDate = MIN(Date)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY ID, SENTTO
)t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID'

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae28f/1/0)

Comment: Thank you Felix. Your Sql fiddle will not load. I am trying to understand your code as I am not advancely experienced in Sql.